# Передача данных из процедур в VB2005

Tags: vb.net, .net

В VB 6 писали процедуру типа:

```
Public b, c, d, e
private sub aaa(ByVal a, ByVal b, ByVal c)
b=a+100
c=sqr(a)
end sub
```

И когда надо было, вызывали эту процедуру и могли присвоить значения b и c значениям d и e, просто написав

```
aaa(a,d,e)
```

Однако в VB8  такой метод не работает: переменным d и e присваиваются пустые значения. Помогите, как видоизменить процедуру, чтоб значения присваивались.

Comment: VB... Как давно это было...

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения внешний переменных, переданных в функцию, нужно использовать `ByRef`:

```
Private Sub aaa(ByVal a, ByRef b, ByRef c)
    b = a + 100
    c = Math.Sqrt(a)
End Sub
```